# A single word or phrase for the subjects in school

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or phrase that covers all subjects of the basic educational subjects (i.e. math, reading, science, writing, history)? I know of the "Three Rs", but I'm looking for something more formal. Here's the context, if that helps:

> To this day, many societies continue to believe that education should be based around **_____**.

Comment: ... the trivium?

Comment: @ermanen Does the trivium and quadrivium middle-ages reference still apply?

Comment: @Third News: They are historical terms but can be mentioned as an extra information maybe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about the phrase Core Curriculum?

"A core curriculum is a curriculum, or course of study, which is deemed central and usually made mandatory for all students of a school or school system."

[Wikipedia: Curriculum#Core_curriculum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum#Core_curriculum)

Comment: You may quote the explanation of core curriculum from here: [Curriculum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum)

Comment: This is common where I'm from; "core classes" are the essential academic classes. Mathematics, sciences, English, and history.

Comment: If you use the phrase Core Curriculum in the US, be aware that it may be assumed you are referring to the Common Core curriculum designed at the federal level, and which is somewhat controversial. Depending on context, this may not even be a possibility, but it's worth knowing it exists.

Answer (score 1):

*Academic Syllabus* or simply *Syllabus*.

Usage-

> To this day, many societies continue to believe that education should be based around *academic syllabus*.

Or

> To this day, many societies continue to believe that education should be based around *academic **studies***.

Answer (score 1):

> To this day, many societies continue to believe that education should be based around the [mastery of the fundamentals](http://www.newspapers.com/newspage/4227922/).

Answer (score -1):

*Academia* comes to mind - but it might be broader than you asked for.

Comment: This word is usually used to refer to the broader academic community rather than academic classes or even classes in general—I don't think it's suitable here.